# What are the security reasons for not allowing get requests with MVC/ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

ASP.NET MVC doesn't allow json GET requests anymore unless explicitly enabled with `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`. I have several AJAX requests that I would like to have cached for example, so I would like to allow GET requests on them.

What exactly are the security implications with enabling GET requests, and how can I counter them in another way?

Comment: you're right, didn't see that one.